# DDR1 memory recommandation for reviving an old pc

Tags: memory, compatibility, upgrade

I would like to revive an old pc (as a linux server) by adding more rams to it. Could you kindly recommend me some 1GB or 2GB sticks which will work with the bellow configuration? (I wouldn't throw the stick I already have - no one will buy an old ddr1)

Configuration:

- CPU: AMD Sempron 2600, socket 754, 32bit;
- MB:  Asus K8N;
- RAM: 1 Kingmax stick with 256MB, ddr1 @400MHz, CL2.5, IC: 32Mbx8, FHAS, MPXB62D-38KT3R, S/N: E53023514001

I'd looked on Kingmax site, but they don't seem to have a forum; the ram details (found on local stores) are not always clear and I don't want to buy something incompatible and something reducing the ram performance.

(The CPU will be upgraded to an AMD Athlon64, so maybe >4GB will work on this machine, but the main focus here, are the rams)

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see any point in pursuing this unless you specifically want to revive it as a museum piece.

It has only three RAM slots & takes 1GB sticks for a total of 3GB.
See https://www.memorystock.com/memory/ASUSK8N.html for details.

By the time you've bought three of these you could have bought an entire working second hand computer from around 2010 from a junk shop/eBay.

Comment: thank you. I'll monitor the site you provided, maybe I'll see some >=1GB @400MHz CL2.5 non-ECC sticks, in the near future.